# Server failure probability

Tags: probability

Let's say my boss wants me to come up with a server configuration in a such way that the probability of having no servers up is at most $1\%$ over the course of a year, knowing that the probability of one server going down in a given year is $0.05$. Assuming that one server failing will have no impact on the other servers, how many servers do I need to comply with the boss's demand? How much safety do I get out of an extra server?

I feel like I am missing something, as solving $0.05^n \le 0.01$ seems way too easy.

Comment: If a server goes down, does it stay down permanently (for the rest of the year)? If it comes back up (eg out for a month), then it becomes complicated

Comment: My guess is that it stays down permanently, as the exercise doesn't mention anything else.

Comment: You are missing a condition $n>1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the answer to my question in the comments, because of particular numbers which you've chosen, $n = 2$ is correct whatever it means. As a worst case, it goes down permanently; anything else (keeping the independence) will simply increase the number which are on at any one time.

Then you just need $1$ to 'survive'; that is, the probability that all fail (and you have stated that they are independent) has to be at most $0.01$. Clearly $0.05^2 = 0.0025 < 0.01$, and so the minimal $n$ is $n = 2$. (Note that $n = 1$ gives probabiltiy $0.05 > 0.01$.)